# Sorting comments with nested replies

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to come up with a query that will return comments following their replies and its replies.

Something like

```
comment 1
reply 1.1
reply 1.1.1
reply 1.2
comment 2
comment 3
comment 3.1
```

etc

I have this so far

```
SELECT [CommentID]
  ,[ParentID]
  ,[Message]
  , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by ParentID order by CommentID ) as rn
  ,[CreatedBy]
  ,[CreatedDate]
  FROM [DBNAME].[dbo].[Commenttable] 
  GROUP BY [CommentID],[ParentID],[CreatedDate],[Message],[CreatedBy]
```

but what I get is

```
comment 1
comment 2
comment 3
reply 1.1
reply 1.2
reply 3.1
reply 1.1.1
```

Basic Structure is just a table with Comment ID, Parent ID, and the message. 
The comments and replies are just to help explain what I am trying to achieve

Comment: Can tell much by your structure and lack of details, but try adding an ORDER BY ParentID, CommentID clause after your group by

Comment: Try ordering by your second column in the result set.

Comment: make all your version number consistent... ie. 1.0.0, 2.0.0 instead of 1 and 2.  or split them off into separate fields.  versionnumber, subversionnumber etc.

Comment: if you cannot make schema changes... create functions to extract those components of the version number.  (not worrying about performance implications of using functions for now)

Comment: @samyi: Those "version numbers" may only be there to indicate which comment is a response to which else one, so that we could see how they should be sorted. I mean, perhaps they are just for us. They are not necessarily present in the table in that form. Even if they were, you should probably not expect there to be a definite maximum level of nesting. I mean, there could be a reply 10 levels deep, or no replies at all, you just wouldn't know how many `.0`s to append (without "previewing" the table first, which would likely mean a double job).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
declare @CommentTable as Table ( CommentId Int Identity, ParentId Int Null, Message VarChar(16) )
insert into @CommentTable ( ParentId, Message ) values
  ( null, '1' ),
  ( null, '2' ), ( 1, '1.1' ),
  ( null, '3' ), ( 4, '3.1' ), ( 3, '1.1.1' ), ( 1, '1.2' )
select * from @CommentTable

; with Cindy as (
  -- Start with the base comments.
  select CommentId, ParentId, Message, Row_Number() over ( order by CommentId ) as Number,
    Cast( Row_Number() over ( order by CommentId ) as VarChar(1000) ) as Path,
    Cast( Right( '0000' + Cast( Row_Number() over ( order by CommentId ) as VarChar(4) ), 5 ) as VarChar(1000) ) as OrderPath
    from @CommentTable
    where ParentId is NULL
  union all
  -- Add replies on layer at a time.
  select CT.CommentId, CT.ParentId, CT.Message, Row_Number() over ( order by CT.CommentId ),
    Cast( C.Path + '.' + Cast( Row_Number() over ( order by CT.CommentId ) as VarChar(4) ) as VarChar(1000) ),
    Cast( C.OrderPath + Right( '0000' + Cast( Row_Number() over ( order by CT.CommentId ) as VarChar(4) ), 5 ) as VarChar(1000) )
    from @CommentTable as CT inner join
      Cindy as C on C.CommentId = CT.ParentId
  )
  select *
    from Cindy
    order by OrderPath
```