# SQL Server RETURN in order recursive query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ms-access-2010

I have a recursive query which outputs a BOM (Bill of Materials) and it does output all of the levels. however the problem is that it is out of order when the procedure is called this is in either access and SQL Server. And if there are no child parts, then the part is nothing is returned.

**Code**

Create/Alter table:

```sql
USE [<Database>]

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO    

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE BOM
(
    [POSITION] INT CHECK ([POSITION] >= 0),
    [PARENT] VARCHAR(10),
    [PART] VARCHAR(10),
    [QUANTITY] INT NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Create/Alter procedure:

```sql
USE [<Database>]

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Description: GETS BOM GIVEN PARAMETER
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE GETBOM 
    @TL VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH TESTBOM AS
    (
        SELECT 
            [POSITION], [PARENT], [PART], [QUANTITY]
        FROM 
            BOM
        WHERE  
            [PART] = @TL 
            AND [Parent] IS NULL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            E.[POSITION], E.[PARENT], E.[PART], E.[QUANTITY]
        FROM 
            BOM E  
        INNER JOIN 
            TESTBOM M ON E.[PARENT] = M.[PART] 
    )
    SELECT * FROM TESTBOM
END
GO
```

Sample data:

| POSITION | PARENT | PART | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | A | 1 |
| 1 | A | B | 1 |
| 0 |  | B | 1 |
| 1 | B | E | 1 |
| 2 | B | F | 1 |
| 0 |  | F | 1 |
| 1 | F | K | 1 |
| 2 | F | C | 1 |
| 0 |  | C | 1 |
| 1 | C | G | 2 |
| 2 | C | H | 1 |
| 2 | A | C | 1 |
| 3 | A | D | 1 |
| 0 |  | D | 1 |
| 1 | D | I | 1 |
| 0 |  | I | 1 |
| 1 | I | L | 1 |
| 2 | I | M | 2 |
| 2 | D | J | 1 |

**Outputs**

**A**:

```
EXEC GETBOM 'A'
```

[image: output A]

**B**:

```
EXEC GETBOM 'B'
```

[image: output B]

**C**

```
EXEC GETBOM 'C'
```

[image: output C]

**D**

```
EXEC GETBOM 'D'
```

[image: output D]

**E**

```
EXEC GETBOM 'E'
```

[image: output E]

Comment: If you want your data in a specific order, you need an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Your recursive query doesn't appear to accumulate a _Path_ or other suitable value on which to sort to get the "usual" BoM order.

Comment: @HABO So is there a way to dynamically create the path ( as in create it with the recursion) or do you have to set it manually (as in with the tables and user input).

Comment: @Larnu I do know that there is ` ORDER BY`  however, The order would not work because in one level there is a position 1 and in a lower level there is also a position 1.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077474/92546) answer demonstrates one technique that could be bent to fit BoMs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what you need here without proper sample data, but it seems if you concatenate each item's position with all its parents, you can order by that.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE GETBOM 
@TL VARCHAR(10)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

WITH TESTBOM AS
(
    SELECT POSITION, PARENT, PART, QUANTITY, CAST(POSITION AS nvarchar(100)) AS Ordering
    FROM BOM
    WHERE [PART] = @TL
      and [Parent] is null

    UNION ALL

    SELECT E.[POSITION],E.[PARENT],E.[PART],E.[QUANTITY], CAST(CONCAT(M.Ordering, E.POSITION) AS nvarchar(200)) 
    FROM BOM E
    INNER JOIN TESTBOM M ON E.[PARENT]=M.[PART] 
)
SELECT
  POSITION, PARENT, PART, QUANTITY
FROM TESTBOM
ORDER BY
  Ordering;
```

Comment: Without explicit formatting this is like to fail with multi-digit values, e.g. is `121` `12` and `1`, or `1` and `21`, or `121`?

Comment: True, I didn't have sample data to test so didn't notice. Yes `hierarchyid` is probably a better idea

Answer (score 1):

The following code assembles a [`hierarchyid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference?view=sql-server-ver16) as it walks down through assembling the BoM recursively ([dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a0948e754b79ce453055b625a6be58f7)).

Sample data:

```
-- Sample data.
declare @BoM as table (
  Position Int Check ( Position >= 0 ),
  Parent VarChar(10),
  Part VarChar(10),
  Quantity Int not NULL );

insert into @BoM ( Position, Parent, Part, Quantity ) values
  ( 0, NULL, 'A', 1 ),
  ( 1, 'A', 'B', 1 ),
  ( 0, NULL, 'B', 1 ),
  ( 1, 'B', 'E', 1 ),
  ( 2, 'B', 'F', 3 ), -- Changed quantity from 1 to 3 to show extended quantity.
  ( 0, NULL, 'F', 1 ),
  ( 1, 'F', 'K', 1 ),
  ( 2, 'F', 'C', 1 ),
  ( 0, NULL, 'C', 1 ),
  ( 1, 'C', 'G', 2 ),
  ( 2, 'C', 'H', 1 ),
  ( 2, 'A', 'C', 1 ),
  ( 3, 'A', 'D', 1 ),
  ( 0, NULL, 'D', 1 ),
  ( 1, 'D', 'I', 1 ),
  ( 0, NULL, 'I', 1 ),
  ( 1, 'I', 'L',  1 ),
  ( 2, 'I', 'M', 2 ),
  ( 2, 'D', 'J', 1 );

select * from @BoM;
```

Recursive query:

```
-- Starting point for building a BoM.
declare @BasePart as VarChar(10) = 'A';

-- Do the deed.
with
  BoMTree as (
    -- Start with the parentless base part ...
    select Position, Parent, Part, Quantity,
      -- Many BoMs provide the extended quantity for subcomponents.
      Quantity as ExtendedQuantity,
      -- Build a hierarchy to keep track of the order of parts within the BoM.
      Cast( '/' + Cast( Row_Number() over ( order by Position ) as VarChar(4) ) + '/' as VarChar(100) ) as BoMOrder
      from @BoM
      where Part = @BasePart and Parent is NULL
    union all
    -- ... and add additional levels of parts one at a time.
    select B.Position, B.Parent, B.Part, B.Quantity,
      -- Extend the quantity.
      B.Quantity * BT.ExtendedQuantity,
      -- Add another level to the hierarchy.
      Cast( BT.BoMOrder + Cast( Row_Number() over ( order by B.Position ) as VarChar(4) ) + '/' as VarChar(100) ) as BoMOrder
      from @BoM as B inner join
        BoMTree as BT on B.Parent = BT.Part
    ),
  BoMTreeWithOrder as (
    -- Cast the order from a string to a proper hierarchy id.
    select Position, Parent, Part, Quantity, ExtendedQuantity,
      Cast( BoMOrder as HierarchyId ) as BoMOrderHI
      from BoMTree )
  -- Display the indented BoM.
  select Position, Parent,
    Space( ( BoMOrderHI.GetLevel() - 1 ) * 2 ) + Part as Part,
    Quantity,
    ExtendedQuantity, BoMOrderHI
    from BomTreeWithOrder
    order by BoMOrderHI;
```