# Recursive CTE showing all levels of ragged-hierarchy BOMs

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, azure-synapse, recursive-query

I’m trying to create a recursive query in T-SQL This query should return all active BOMs and the hierarchy of parts through all levels of each BOM.

I cannot use temporary tables, as I am using Azure Synapse serverless.

The **desired output** is this: the first table traces the part through the subcomponents to the parent BOM.

| Child Part No. | Child Part Name | Parent BOM ID | Parent Part No. | Lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15-5H10001.312 | 15-5PH AMS5659 TYPE 1 AMS-H-6875, 150,000 PSI MIN ULT (REF H1000) | BOM0013535 | 9R3212 | 2 |
| 15-5H10001.312 | 15-5PH AMS5659 TYPE 1 AMS-H-6875, 150,000 PSI MIN ULT (REF H1000) | BOM0013536 | 9R3213-2 | 1 |

The second table takes the part and traces it back through the parts / subassemblies all the way down to raw materials:

| Parent Part No. | Child Part No. | Child Part Name | Child BOM ID | Lvl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 293W3001-1 | BUS70M215AT99 | PLUS SEAL BACKUP RING | BOM-015307 | 1 |
| 293W3001-1 | S30855-0215H-99 | GROOVED PLUS SEAL II | BOM0000712 | 2 |
| 293W3001-1 | 293W3002-2 | BARREL, ACTUATOR 3.375 X 12.000 SLUGGED MATERIAL | BOM0003067 | 3 |
| 293W3001-1 | 2C5041-4 | POPPET ANY VENDOR CHANGES, NOTIFY CONTRACTS | BOM0000620 | 4 |
| 293W3001-1 | O130-17-4H1075.1875 | HEAT TREAT | BOM0000924 | 5 |
| 293W3001-1 | 304A.2500 | CENTERLESS GROUND AMS5639, QQ-S-763 | BOM0007194 | 6 |

Normal recursive query strategies don’t seem to work, in part because I don’t have a defined starting point, and in part because the joins are somewhat complicated (it’s not a simple hierarchy of ID-Parent -> ID-Child -> ID-Parent2… hard to explain; hopefully, my code makes it clearer).

I’ve currently something that works, but it’s clunky and only works down to 7-level BOMs; I want something that just goes to the end of the hierarchy, no matter how deep it is (I’ll only give you the first two select statements, to minimize clutter:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  H.BOMID AS ParentBOMID  
    , H.BOMName AS ParentPartID  
    , I1.ItemName AS ParentPartName   
    , H.BOMID AS ChildBOMID  
    , L.ItemNumber AS ChildPartNumber  
    , I2.ItemName AS ChildPartName  
    , [Level] = 1 
FROM ARBBOMItemSpecificBillOfMaterialsHeaderEntity AS H 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bi.DIM_Item AS I1  
    ON H.BOMName = I1.ItemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ARBBOMBillOfMaterialsLineEntity AS L  
    ON H.BOMID = L.BOMID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bi.DIM_Item AS I2  
    ON L.ItemNumber = I2.ItemID  

UNION  

SELECT  
    H.BOMID AS ParentBOMID  
    , H.BOMName AS ParentPartID  
    , I1.ItemName AS ParentPartName   

    , H2.BOMID AS ChildBOMID  
    , L2.ItemNumber AS ChildPartNumber  
    , I3.ItemName AS ChildPartName  
    , [Level] = 2 
FROM ARBBOMItemSpecificBillOfMaterialsHeaderEntity AS H 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bi.DIM_Item AS I1  
    ON H.BOMName = I1.ItemID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ARBBOMBillOfMaterialsLineEntity AS L  
    ON H.BOMID = L.BOMID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bi.DIM_Item AS I2  
    ON L.ItemNumber = I2.ItemID   
LEFT OUTER JOIN ARBBOMBillOfMaterialsHeaderEntity AS H2  
    ON L.ItemNumber = H2.BOMName 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ARBBOMBillOfMaterialsLineEntity AS L2  
    ON H2.BOMID = L2.BOMID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN bi.DIM_Item AS I3  
    ON L2.ItemNumber = I3.ItemID
```

…. and so forth, all the way down to L6 and I7

Comment: Some sample data, as neither of the tables you give us appear to be sample data, in DDL and DML statements, would be really helpful here.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72671796/92546) answer shows a typical recursive CTE using a `HierarchyId` to generate an indented BoM. If `HierarchyId` isn't an option then something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10077474/92546) answer can be used.

Comment: Moving recursively UP or DOWN thru hierarchy -  task is common and has been discussed many times. If you give an example of a data structure and an example of data, it is quite possible to suggest a solution.